# Find the coordinates for A

Tags: integration

A is located on $g(x)=x$, where $x>0$. From A a line, parallel to the y-axis, is drawn. The second graph is f(x)= $x^3$. Find the coordinates for A so that area C=area B.

This is what I have done so far:
Since A is located on a linear function the x-value equals the y-value. Lets say A= (a,a). $f(x)=x^3$ will then intersect the parallel line in (a,y), since they have the same x-coordinate.

Area of C

$\int_0^a (upper function-lower function) =g(x)-f(x)~dx = (x-x^3)dx= \left [\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4} \right ]_0^a = \frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^4}{4}$

Area of B

$\int_0^a (upper function-lower function) =(f(x)-0)~dx = (x^3-0)dx= \left [\frac{x^4}{4}-0 \right ]_0^a = \frac{a^4}{4}$

C=B

$\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^4}{4}$ =$\frac{a^4}{4}$

I get a=0 which doesn't make sense.

Here is an image to illustrate the problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You get $\frac{a^2}2=\frac{a^4}2$. Taking $a=0$ doesn't make sense indeed. But $a=1$ is a solution too. And that solves the problem.

Comment: Note that $a = 0$ makes a lot of sense: Both areas become $0$, which means they are equal. I would've been very surprised if $a = 0$ _didn't_ come out of the calculations. However, it is _most likely_ not the answer that is asked for.

Comment: Mostly agree with you, but my guess is that whover created the exercise was thinking about regions with area greater than $0$.

Comment: Someone said that the area of B is half of C+B. Can I use that to calculate the coordinates?

Comment: What else do you need? $A=(a,a)=(1,1)$, right?!